# Opposite of "to put off"

Tags: expressions, phrasal-verbs

Is there any word, expression or phrasal verb I can use that has the opposite meaning of "put off"?

The case I have in mind is this:

The meeting would be on saturday, but a lot of things have happened, so we'll have to ___________ for wednesday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [advance](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Advance):   (fron TFD)

> - to cause to occur sooner.

The meeting will be advanced to Wednesday

Comment: Ok, that's good, but what's "TFD"?
Thanks.

Comment: The Free Dictionary as per link attached.

Answer (score 1):

Indian English has a very logical word for the opposite of *postpone*: [*prepone*](/q/808/16310).

Answer (score 0):

...so we'll have to move it forward to Wednesday.